# Unable to get `cider-jack-in` to work

Tags: clojure, cider

See an error message: `error in process sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: That’s not a task. Use "lein help" to list all tasks.`

In the `*Messages*` buffer, the full form of the error is:

> error in process sentinel: nrepl-server-sentinel: Could not start nREPL server: That’s not a task. Use "lein help" to list all tasks.

`M-x cider-version` shows

> CIDER 0.15.0snapshot (package: 20170525.255)

Tried fiddling around with `~/.lein/profiles.clj` to explicitly add in

```
{:user {:plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.15.0snapshot"]]}}`
```

... but that didn't change anything.

(getting back to Clojure after a while with a "fresh" install (Emacs, clojure-mode, cider, etc. so might have missed some small environment setup step, just don't know what that is!)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the incompatibility was not with the nRepl middleware, but with Leiningen itself.

Once I uninstalled the version I had installed using `apt-get`, and self-installed using the [downloaded script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/technomancy/leiningen/stable/bin/lein), and made sure this new version was what `which lein` led to, this problem went away.

*More details*: Running `cider-jack-in` was triggering a call to `lein update-in` with further arguments, but the version of Leiningen I had simply didn't show `update-in` as one of the options when I ran `lein help`.